# Is it possible to format a textbox as currency using code behind

Tags: wpf

I have a textbox on a WPF Window (form) that is NOT "bound" using Databinding. I am looking for a way to format the textbox as Currency using code.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any further detail:

```
var myNumber = 45.78d;
MyTextBox.Text = myNumber.ToString("C");
```

You can learn more about formatting numbers on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: Got it. My original problem is that I was trying to do it using the value of the textbox without converting it to a decimal first. So I was getting this error: The best overloaded method match for 'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments. Once I seen your sample I added the Convert.ToDecimal and it work as I would expect. Thanks.